# Pass double pointer parameter through P/Invoke when it is NULL

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, pinvoke

I try to call FFMPEG method via P/Invoke

```
 int avformat_find_stream_info(AVFormatContext *ic, AVDictionary **options);
```

So my P/Invoke method defined like this:

```
[DllImport("avformat-55", EntryPoint = "avformat_find_stream_info", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public extern static int AVFormatFindStreamInfo(IntPtr ic, ref IntPtr options);
```

and I need pass an IntPtr.Zero for the options, so I call this way:

```
var p = IntPtr.Zero;
rst = AVFormatFindStreamInfo(context, ref p);
```

and an AccessViolation exception throws.

But when I remove the ref from the signature, and directly pass an IntPtr.Zero to it, it actually works.
I think the signature with ref keyword is the right way, but I don't know why the exception throws.

Comment: Why do you think the signature with `ref` is the right way?

Comment: @31eee384 , Doesn't `ref IntPtr` represents the double pointer? If not, the pointer and the double pointer all represented by IntPtr?

Comment: Maybe I'm poking my nose where it doesn't belong, but `ref IntPtr` just means a ref to an `IntPtr` to me--to be more specific, a reference to a managed struct. An `IntPtr` itself represents `void *`, so it could point to a pointer just as easily as it could point to an object. So it makes sense to me that the single `IntPtr` works.

Comment: @Bart ref IntPtr can be double pointer. Depends what is meant by double pointer. The type alone doesn't specify the intent. In this case you can't pass NULL through ref IntPtr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with

```
ref IntPtr options
```

That will also pass the address of an `IntPtr` variable to the unmanaged code. And that address can never be `NULL`. If you need to be able to pass `NULL` to the unmanaged code it must be

```
IntPtr options
```

And you pass `IntPtr.Zero`.

You can either do this with two overloads. One as you have it for when you want to receive an options object, and one as in this answer for when you do not. Or, you can use a single overload, the version from this answer, and manually pin an `IntPtr` variable when you need to receive an options variable.

Comment: Strangely, I tried pass NULL to unmanaged code I defined, and it works.              C#: `[DllImport("FFMPEG-cpp", EntryPoint = "doSomthing1", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]  public extern static IntPtr DoSomthing1(ref IntPtr s);  var NULL = IntPtr.Zero;  var s = DoSomthing1(ref NULL);` C++: `__declspec(dllexport) const char* doSomthing1(const char** c)  { return "Bart111";} ` . I debug into the unmanaged code, and the parameter c is NULL

Comment: No it is not. `*c` is `NULL`.

Comment: OK, I got it. I debugged again, and found `*c` is `NULL`, and `**c` is not `NULL`. Most unmanaged code will simply check whether `**c` is `NULL` to infer whether the caller has passed the parameter.

Comment: And I think the  `two overloads` solution to call the unmanaged method that contains double pointer is complicated. If the method signature contains N double pointers, does that mean I need create 2^N P/Invoke method signatures for that?

Comment: In practice the number of overloads you need tends to be manageable. I think I answered your question.